# How to copy all the data without schema from one database to another in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I want to copy the entire data (only data, not schema) from one database to another in Postgres,
given that both the databases have a similar schema except the varchar length.

I can't use the template copy method because it overwrites the schema as well.
`CREATE DATABASE [Database to create] WITH TEMPLATE [Database to copy] OWNER [Your username];`

I can very well use `psql testdb -c 'COPY tableName TO stdout' | psql targetdbs -c 'COPY tableName FROM stdin'` to copy data table by table like this, but what I need is to copy all the tables in one shot.

Comment: `pg_dump` with `--data-only`

Comment: It seems my user doesn't have permission to run pg_dump, I have to do it in Production DB

Comment: If you can run `copy` you can use `pg_dump`